# Does the Ubuntu Snap-store support Flatpak

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, gnome-software, snap-store

I had troubles with the Ubuntu Software App (20.04/22.04), it simply wasn't starting.

I found out that although the app is still advertised as Ubuntu-Software it is actually a snap called `snap-store`.

And that is a mess, in the Activities you have to search for `ubuntu-software` and CLI for `snap-store`.

As it seems Ubuntu is moving more and more to snaps, I thought Ubuntu-software was renamed version of gnome-software, but not anymore as it seems.

Anyhow, I succeeded in updating Ubuntu-Software/snap-store (killing it first to be able to do `snap refresh snap-store`), but I can't find any references to Flatpak installs in the snap store.

How do I get support for Flatpak in the `snap-store`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Ubuntu Software" does not support flatpak.

If you wish flatpak support in the software center, you could install Gnome Software instead:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software gnome-software-plugin-flatpak gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

This installs both flatpak and snap support in Gnome Software.

You can optionally remove Ubuntu Software with `sudo snap remove snap-store`.

Comment: Thx, I would suggest removing snap-store to clean up the mess. BTW `sudo apt install --install-suggests gnome-software` is shorter and does the same